# Update master/child rows

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, datatable, identity, relation

I have tables `Cases` and `Degrees` with relation `Cases.CID` - `CDegrees.CID`. `CID` is Primary Key of `Cases` with AutoIncrement.

Both tables are used in one form and it's assumed that user can add new records to both tables same time and than save whole master/child data in one GUI action.

So in Dataset where I created FK I set "Both Relation and Foreign Key Constraint" to ensure during update of new record in Cases table, retrieved IDENTITY value will cause child records to update from -1 to retrieved `CID` value.

When I update `Cases` adapter, it causes to retrieve an new IDENTITY value and cascade update in `CDegrees` child record works ok too. But `CDegrees`'s update causes Insert script with [CID]=-1 (original value). I changed Insert parameter `@CID` of `CDegrees` to "Proposed" version but same happens (seen in SQL Profiler).

Actually my task is mach more complicated, I just simplified task to localize my problem.

---

To describe more clearly.
before update
Both [Cases] and [CDegrees] have one new records with [CID]=-1
after [Cases] update both [Cases] and [CDegrees] have new CID identity value, just [CDegrees].[CID] "Current" value is -1 and "Proposed" is retrieved identity.
But when I call [CDegrees]'s dataset update, it sends Insert Command to SQL with [CID]=-1 regardless that I specified @CID parameter source as proposed value of [CID].

Answer (score 0):

That is strange and funny. It appeared that calendar control on detailsform somehow causes but preventing details data cascade update according master identity value of `CID` field.
I just changed date field bound control from `MonthCalendar` to `DateTimePicker` and it worked.